# Как можно переписать код с другим драйвером?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, yii2

До этого осуществлялся запрос через sqlsrv вместе со встроенной процедурой и входным параметром

но сложилось так, что драйвер для sqlsrv не возможно использовать, а mysql_connect не работает на новой версии php. Подскажите как можно переписать код ниже и аналогично подключиться к базе данных, но через любой другой драйвер?

```
$db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'driverName' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=111.111.11.111;Database=name',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);

$SN = 1111111111;

$result = $db->createCommand("EXECUTE procedurename :paramname")
    ->bindValue(':prod',$serialnumber)
    ->queryAll();
```

Буду рада любой помощи

Comment: Если у вас MSSQL сервер, то никакой mysql вам не поможет. Это разные серверы. лучше опишите текущую проблему подробнее или уточните окружение в котором работает ваш код

Comment: `mysql_connect` вообще стар ). Попробуйте `mysqli_connect`